# What is correct way to use library installed with CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I just started using `CocoaPods` so most probably my question is trivial. I've read couple tutorials about installation different libraries with CocoaPods. All they advise add line like `pod 'ImagePicker'` to target section in Podfile, run "pod install" and open *.xcworkspace file.

After that I try to use my library, but get error

> Use of unresolved identifier *

Adding line like `import ImagePicker` to my class fixes this issue. But in tutorials I've read there are no any mention about importing libraries. Is it required step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right

```
import SomeLibrary
```

At the top of your swift file is required

Comment: Exactly. When you link some library throw CocoaPods and install it you just add this library files to your workspace (as an additional target for Pods project). But to use this library you still should import it to the file you wanna use it in.
import .... for swift
#import <...> for Obj-C

Comment: Thank you! The fact of importing library wasn't mention in tutorials and that confused me.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you import UIKit or Foundation, you need to import the name of the library into each file in which you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Swift library, the process should work. If it is an Objective-C library, Bridging-Header is required ([See this link](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/)).
Then add

```
import LibraryName
```

at the top of the swift file.